# Can I get help to get the desired output with Xquery?

Tags: xquery

I have this DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!ELEMENT MusicCatalog (Artist*,Album*,Genre+,Company*,Country*)>


<!ELEMENT Artist (Name)>
<!ELEMENT Name (FirstName,MiddleName*,LastName?)>
<!ELEMENT FirstName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT MiddleName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LastName (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST  Artist ArtistID ID #REQUIRED
                  countryID IDREF #REQUIRED>



<!ELEMENT Album (Title,Price,Year)>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Year (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Album AlbumID ID #REQUIRED
                ArtistID IDREF #REQUIRED
                CompanyID IDREF #REQUIRED
                GenreName IDREFS #REQUIRED >

<!ELEMENT Company (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST Company CompanyID ID #REQUIRED>


<!ELEMENT Genre EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Genre GenreName ID #REQUIRED>


<!ELEMENT Country (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Country countryID ID #REQUIRED>
```

and I Have this basic XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MusicCatalog SYSTEM "Refined_DTD_For_catalog.dtd">
<MusicCatalog>

  <Artist ArtistID="Ar_0000" countryID="US">
    <Name>
      <FirstName>Katey </FirstName>
      <LastName>Berry</LastName>
    </Name>
  </Artist>

    <Artist ArtistID="Ar_0001" countryID="US">
    <Name>
      <FirstName>Justine </FirstName>
      <LastName>Temrilke</LastName>
    </Name>
  </Artist> 


   <Album AlbumID="AL_0000" ArtistID="Ar_0000" CompanyID="C_3" GenreName="Pop HipHop R_and_B">
      <Title>Calfornia Girls</Title>
      <Price>12</Price>      
      <Year>2012</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0001" ArtistID="Ar_0000" CompanyID="C_1" GenreName="Pop HipHop R_and_B">
      <Title>Confessions</Title>
      <Price>9</Price>
      <Year>2008</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0002" ArtistID="Ar_0000" CompanyID="C_10" GenreName="Pop HipHop R_and_B">
      <Title>Roar</Title>
      <Price>13</Price>
      <Year>2014</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0003" ArtistID="Ar_0000" CompanyID="C_4" GenreName=" HipHop R_and_B">
      <Title>Teenge Dream</Title>
      <Price>11</Price>
      <Year>2010</Year>
    </Album>  
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0004" ArtistID="Ar_0001" CompanyID="C_4" GenreName="HipHop R_and_B">
      <Title>Future of sex</Title>
      <Price>8</Price>
      <Year>2007</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0005" ArtistID="Ar_0001" CompanyID="C_5" GenreName="HipHop">
      <Title>Mirros</Title>
      <Price>8</Price>
      <Year>2013</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0006" ArtistID="Ar_0001" CompanyID="C_5" GenreName="Electro">
      <Title>Holly Grail</Title>
      <Price>9</Price> 
      <Year>2014</Year>
    </Album>
    <Album AlbumID="AL_0007" ArtistID="Ar_0001" CompanyID="C_6" GenreName="HipHop Electro">
      <Title>Give it to me</Title>
      <Price>5</Price>
      <Year>2005</Year>
    </Album>

    <Genre GenreName="Rap"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Country"/>
    <Genre GenreName="R_and_B"/>
    <Genre GenreName="HipHop"/>
    <Genre GenreName="House"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Pop"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Electro"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Blues"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Punck"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Rock"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Metal"/>
    <Genre GenreName="Alternative_Rock"/>

  <Company CompanyID="C_1">
   CBS Records
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_2">
  RCA
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_3">
    WEA   
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_4">
  Cloumbia
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_5">
   Virgin Records 
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_6">   
  Pickwick
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_7">
   Atlantic
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_8">
   Mega
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_9">
   Grammy
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_10">
   Wordo
  </Company>
  <Company CompanyID="C_11">
    Fox
  </Company>


  <Country countryID="US">
    United State  
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="UK">
    United Kingdom
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="FR">
    France
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="GR">
    Germany
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="ME">
    Mexico
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="SP">
    Spain
  </Country>
  <Country countryID="JP">
    Japneas
  </Country>

</MusicCatalog>
```

My problem with Xquery is I'm not getting what the expected result, in this query I'm trying to get companies name, create element with name and indie it to get the all albums titles but I'm getting only the company id, I tried to solve with many queries but most of it don't work

```
 for $dc in distinct-values( //Album/@CompanyID ) 
 return element {string ($dc)} { 
   for $j in //Album[@CompanyID = $dc] return $j/Title 
 }
```

This another try

```
for $i in distinct-values(//MusicCatalog/Album/@CompanyID)  
return 
    if(compare($i,//MusicCatalog/Company/@CompanyID)) 
        then "element {string(//MusicCatalog/Company)}"

    {
        for $j in //MusicCatalog/Album[@CompanyID eq $i] return $j/Title
    }

}
```

I getting  this

```
<c_3>
<title>Calfornia Girls</title>
<title>Roar/title>
</c_3>
```

while I want to get

```
<WEA>
<title>Calfornia Girls</title>
    <title>Roar/title>
</WEA>
```

another problem is with getting genre albums beacuse it's mutlipe IDrefs .

Comment: A bit of clarity wouldn't hurt. What do you mean by company name? You want all the album nodes with a company_id attribute set to a particular value?

Comment: What I mean I need to Creat the Element with data inside the company tag ,not the the Id of the comany then list inside this element what ,the albums.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the company name as element name, you should not pass the id, but the name. I.e. search the name with another path expression:

```
for $i in distinct-values(//MusicCatalog/Album/@CompanyID)  
return 
    element {translate(normalize-space(//MusicCatalog/Company[@CompanyID eq $i]), " ", "_")}

    {
        for $j in //MusicCatalog/Album[@CompanyID eq $i]
        return $j/Title
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ansqwer , but I tried this before and it gives an error "Invalid element Name .Invalid Qname{CBS Records}.

Comment: well, you cannot use spaces in xml names. I edited it to replace spaces by "_"

Comment: do translate() function  need more than one argument ?

Comment: It needs three: The input string that should be changed, the characters you want to remove, and the characters you want to put in as replacement